# Magento 2.3.5 email template country directive issue

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates, format, template-directive, multi-language

The website has two languages, **en_US** and **de_DE**. Both are translated correctly, everything is as it should be. But, when I submit an order, see the attachment below.

I've also tried to submit an order through the german language of the website and this is what I got into my inbox:
Notice: Undefined index: directiveName in `/usr/www/users/xyz/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/DirectiveProcessor/SimpleDirective.php on line 68`

Then I discovered the line, which was triggering this error (upon removing it, at least the e-mail data went through with incorrect formatting for the country again):
`<p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>`

tl;dr weird country formatting in e-mail only for both languages (see attachment)

Thank you in advance,
F[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, disabled frontend translator.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/193367)

Comment: I did not do such thing, I have accepted my own reply as the answer because I have solved the problem myself. You were more welcome to help me instead of posting your comment after the answer was picked.